# Database for dummies

Tags: java, database, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I need a free database for my web app made in Java EE 6. I use glassfish server V3.0.
Could someone recommend me one that is easy to setup and use(for dummies :) )? And also some good instructions.

I just had a horrible experience trying to install MySQL 5.5. It was impossible for me to connect to the database, i was getting all the time a 10061 error, i tried everything and i just gave up. Just please dont tell me MySQL :)

Also i want to mention that i use winXP SP3 and my programming IDE is eclipse Helios

Comment: Its only difficult on Windows ;-)

Comment: MySQL isn't that difficult on Windows either, if my experience is typical.  I'd go back to the start and try again.

Comment: @duffymo: The installation and setup is indeed pretty cake on Windows as well... its getting it integrated with other things that can sometimes be a headache - at least as compared to using a package manager on *nix to install/configure an entire LAMP stack in one command. Thats why i always use WAMP or something similar on Windows. However, id be willing to bet someone elses money the OP's issue was the great confusion over `localhost` vs. `127.0.0.1` :-)

Comment: Note that Glassfish comes with JavaDB Server (aka DerbyDB) bundled. So you do not need to install any other database (if JavaDB fits your needs) - See my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's little that's easy about Oracle.

I'd recommend PostgreSQL if MySQL won't work for you.  It has a very nice admin console, too.  You might like that better than the command shell.

Or maybe Derby, the database that's built into JDK 6 and higher.

Or perhaps Hypersonic SQL.

Comment: I would like to know how configure the my eclipse app to use the derby DB, but not in embeded mode. Can i do that from the glassfish server console?

Comment: See http://weblogs.java.net/blog/lancea/archive/2006/02/starting_derby.html.  Also, you'll need to setup a datasource and look up the connection using JNDI.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I did start using derby successfully, thanks for the recomendation. Also i found this interesting blog with instructions if someone wants to have a look: http://passogobbera.blogspot.com/2011/01/glassfish-v3-derby-db-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Mysql.  :)  Seriously, it is THE most popular open source database.  Postgres is good too, but Mysql is undoubtedly more popular and you're going to find more hosts that provide you a Mysql database, for instance (if that matters).

Try a Windows LAMP (Linux, Apache, Mysql) package.  For instance, try WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/).  This will come with phpmyadmin, a pretty good web based admin console for Mysql.

Otherwise, you could try SQL Server Express, a free version of Microsoft SQL Server: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're developing for, I'm partial to [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html). It's free, relatively easy to get going, and everything you write against it, will work on an full blown Oracle database. (Since it is basically a full blown Oracle 10g database, just limited).

Answer (score 0):

Note that Glassfish comes with JavaDB (aka DerbyDB) bundled. So you do not need to install any other database (if JavaDB fits your needs)

You can start the database server with the followind command:

```
glassfish-install/bin/asadmin start-database --dbhome directory-path
```

See [this page for more information](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/quickstart/v3-preview2.html#gglmh).